# how to get the notification when UITableview 's section scroll to top?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView that contains many sections and each section has only one cell.

I want to get the notification when a section scroll to top (a section will disappear) and do something.

How to get the notification ?

Comment: look into the UITableViewDelegate https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like the following in your delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    float ypos = rect.origin.y;
    if(y==<your identifier for top>) {
      NSLog(@"I am on top");
    }
    // rest of your code...
}
```

If I understood correctly this should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Given UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, all you have to do is respond to this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```